# Access Violation Exception when using outlook address book

Tags: c#, wpf, access-violation, mapi, outlook-2003

> Environment Win XP , Outlook 2003

1. I have a  WPF component which Open outlook address book using `Interop.MAPI`
2. User will select multiple receipients and select ok, Which then closes the address book.
3. Once pop up is closed i can notice wait cursor comes and in few seconds i get the error message and then my application(WPF) is terminated.

I have spent hours to figure it out still no luck, I have copied the following exception from Event viewer.

- I figured it out there is no issue with the address book module
  because same address book is used in different module where it works
  fine.
- Catch block never reached in that method where i open address book and read selected names.

> Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>       Stack:
>          at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>          at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(System.Object)
>          at System.Windows.Window.Show()
>          at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
>          at xxxxx.Frw.Base.Client.UI.DialogService.ShowDialog(xxxxx.Frw.Base.Client.UI.BaseViewModel)
>          at xxxxx.Frw.Base.Client.UI.DialogService.ShowDialog(xxxxx.Frw.Base.Client.UI.BaseViewModel,
>   System.Windows.Controls.UserControl)
>          at xxxxx.Frw.Region.Reu.Client.UI.ViewModels.ReportHeaderViewModel.ShowDistributionList()
>          at xxxxx.Frw.Region.Reu.Client.UI.ViewModels.ReportHeaderViewModel.b__1(System.Object)
>          at xxxxx.Frw.Base.Client.UI.Commands.RelayCommand.Execute(System.Object)
>          at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(System.Windows.Input.ICommandSource,
>   Boolean)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs,
>   Boolean)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr,
>   System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32,
>   System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr,
>   MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)
>          at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>          at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>          at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
>          at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
>          at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
>          at xxxxx.Frw.Main.Client.UI.App.Main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I couldnt figure out what was causing this issue I found a solution to prevent application crashing,

Since the unhandled exception shows the last invoked managed code method as

> xxxxx.Frw.Base.Client.UI.DialogService.ShowDialog()

I simply added a try catch with `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` method decoration after adding this attribute I was able to catch exception thrown by unmaged MAPI interop and handle application crashing issue.

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public void ShowDialog()
{
 try
  {
  }
 Catch(Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```